# Menu of the library SWRevealViewController in Objective-C open completely before to close

Tags: objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I develop an application on iOS 8 and I use the library SWRevealViewController in order to have a slide out menu, so I use the tutorial : http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

My problem is the menu, when it is open and I select a row in the menu then the menu will open itself more in such a way that all the scene of the menu is visible before to close whereas I don't want it opens more and be totally visible before to close, I want the menu close directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to SWRevealViewController.m and set

```
_rearViewRevealOverdraw = 0.0f; // instead of 60.0f
```

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much it runs